# How to get the list of dates between two dates for particular month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

For example consider this two dates **"2012-04-02"** **"2012-04-30"**
I want to get output as shown below but it should not include this dates **"2012-04-02"** **"2012-04-30"**

```
**COLA**

2012-04-01  
2012-04-03  
2012-04-04  
2012-04-05  
2012-04-06  
2012-04-07
..
..
..
2012-04-29
2012-04-31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1
FROM   (
  SELECT DATE '2012-04-02' + 1 AS start_date,
         DATE '2012-04-30' - 1 AS end_date
  FROM   DUAL
)
CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= end_date;
```

or, a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH dates ( value ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( DATE '2014-04-02' + 1 AS DATE ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT value + 1 FROM dates WHERE value + 1 < DATE '2014-04-30'
)
SELECT * FROM dates;
```

**or, if you are doing it for the entire month except those dates:**

```
WITH boundaries ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2014-04-02', DATE '2014-04-30' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' ) + LEVEL - 1
FROM   boundaries
WHERE  TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' ) + LEVEL - 1 NOT IN ( start_date, end_date )
CONNECT BY TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' ) + LEVEL - 1 <= LAST_DAY( end_date );
```

or:

```
WITH boundaries ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2014-04-02', DATE '2014-04-30' FROM DUAL
),
dates ( value ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' ) FROM boundaries
UNION ALL
  SELECT value + 1 FROM dates WHERE value + 1 <= LAST_DAY( value )
)
SELECT *
FROM   dates d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM boundaries WHERE d.value IN ( start_date, end_date ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, but we should not include the 2014-04-02 and 2014-04-30

Comment: @Jfrd Updated - just increase it to start the day later and finish a day earlier.